# Intellij + springboot + maven + spring-loaded

Tags: maven, debugging, intellij-idea, spring-boot, spring-loaded

I have an issue where debugging stops working in Intellij, when applying Spring-loaded as a dependency to the maven plugin.

**Situation 1 (working):**

Using a autogenerated spring-boot maven (pom.xml) file with a declared "Spring-boot-maven-plugin" I can debug my my app using the debug-maven command in intellij. The pom file looks like this:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**Situation 2 (not working):**

Following the guide lines here: [spring-boot-hot-swapping](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-hotswapping.html) one should add a dependency for spring-loaded, to make use of spring-loaded. The pom file now looks like:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>springloaded</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Debugging the same run-configuration as before does not work. The break-points simply never turns into a "checkmark"  and the code never suspends. Code is now hotswapping as one would expect... If I remove the plugin-dependency again, debugging starts working again...

Please help me make situation two work!

IntelliJ 14.1.3 Ultimate, Java 7, Spring boot 1.2.4, Spring loaded 1.2.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it seems there is no one with an answer to this (nor in IntelliJ forums) i've created an issue:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-142078

Answer (score 3):

Did you try with [spring-devtools](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/17/devtools-in-spring-boot-1-3) (since 1.2.3) ? Use this dependency :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

There is already [a ticket here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3315), it seams the same issue.